# Check if a FlexBuffers buffer is not corrupted in C++

Tags: c++, flatbuffers

I want to use FlexBuffers as a kind of binary format JSON. But since the buffer and its size may be given from an external user, I want to know if there's any way to check if a FlexBuffers buffer with its size is real and not corrupted in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no `Verifier` implemented like for FlatBuffers, and we absolutely should have one. I'd open an issue on GitHub about it.